# CardView isn't clickable because of button inside

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to be able to cancel/accept an order using 2 different buttons, and also click on the card to access the order details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="284dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:elevation="3sp"
            android:text="#Distance"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOrderId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:elevation="3sp"
            android:text="#Order ID"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelOrder"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#CD0202"
            android:elevation="2sp"
            app:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconPadding="2dp"
            app:iconSize="60sp"
            app:iconTint="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnConfirmPickupOrder"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#5CDF5F"
            android:elevation="2sp"
            app:icon="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
            app:iconGravity="textEnd"
            app:iconPadding="1dp"
            app:iconSize="60sp"
            app:iconTint="@color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>`
```

[Design of my card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCzBX.jpg)

When I remove the 2 buttons the card is clickable and I can access the order details.
Is it possible to make the both card and buttons clickable at the same time?

Comment: Please share the code where you perform your clicks.

Comment: yes it is possible to make

Comment: How? can you elaborate?